# PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator not found

Tags: phpunit

I am migrating over from PHPUnit 4.5 where the tests run and pass fine.

In PHPUnit 4.5 we used `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator` which now, obviously doesn't exist in PHPUnit 6.

We are using it like so:

```
public static function getMock()
{
    $generator = new PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator();
    $mock = $generator->generate(
        'ezcDbHandlerMysql',
        array(),
        '',
        true,
        true
    );

    if (class_exists($mock['mockClassName'], false) === false) {
        eval($mock['code']);
    }

    $args = array(
        'host' => TEST_DB_HOST,
        'database' => TEST_DB_NAME,
        'username' => TEST_DB_USER,
        'password' => TEST_DB_PASS,
        'driver-opts' => array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TEST_DB_PERSISTENCE),
    );

    $class = new ReflectionClass($mock['mockClassName']);
    $object = $class->newInstanceArgs(array($args));

    return $object;
}
```

How can I rewrite this to not give a class not found error? I don't know what the PHPUnit 6 equivalent of `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options, you could still sneakily use your old code by switching it out with the namespaced MockObjectGenerator as used in [`getMockClass()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1563). If you follow [the manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) you could use `createMock` and [`getMockBuilder()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest2.php) and set the mock up programmatically. I find the latter provides more convenience as I don't have to set a bunch of parameters to their defaults in order to get the n-th argument I actually care about, e.g. when trying to disable the original constructor call. So upgrading to `getMockBUilder` might be a good choice for you.

Since you have to update your mock usages anyway you might also want to switch out the mock library you are using altogether. PHPUnit comes bundles with [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) which I like best for most use cases. It's an opionated library so doing certain things is harder than with the PHPUnit_Mock library, but I usually use this as a motivator to refactor the code for those cases. There are also other mock libraries out there such as [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) you might want to check out.